# How would I make php folder and create a file into that folder previously created

Tags: php

So I am trying to write a php script that creates a folder with files in it. But the problem is that the folder is being created but the file is not going into the correct destination. Here is the php I have atm:

```
<?php
mkdir("testing");
$filename = "one.html";
$content = file($filename);
$fp = fopen($filename,"w");
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I feel that I am not making myself clear. I want to create a folder in this php tag and in the folder I want one.html to go in it. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
if(!is_dir("testing"))
    mkdir("testing");
$filename = "testing/one.html";
$content = "some text";
file_put_contents($filename, $content);
?>
```

should work. See [file_put_contents](http://php.net/file_put_contents)